# Blazor (detail) page reload causes javascript errors

Tags: c#, blazor

I've built a small Blazor website for myself, using a free template which has a bunch of javascript files with it. 
Everything seems to be working fine except for one thing.

When a user reloads (F5) a project detail page, all the html markup dissapears and the console shows a bunch of error logs, indicating that it cannot find the related javascript files. Reloading any other page works fine.

Here is the razor page

```
@page "/project/{Slug}"

@using DOGA.Data
@using DOGA.Services
@inject ProjectService projectService
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

@if (_project == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <section id="pricing" class="pricing-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="section-title text-center pb-20">
                        <h3 class="title">@_project.Name</h3>
                        <p class="text">
                            @((MarkupString)_project.Description)

                            @if (_project.BulletPointList.Items.Any())
                            {
                                <br />

                                @_project.BulletPointList.Name
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <ul style="text-align:left;">
                                    @foreach (var item in _project.BulletPointList.Items)
                                    {
                                        <li>
                                            <i class="lni-check-mark-circle"></i> @item
                                        </li>
                                    }

                                </ul>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </div> <!-- section title -->
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->
            @foreach (var image in _project.DetailImages)
            {
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-7 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="pricing-style-one mt-40 wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                            <div class="pricing-header text-center">
                                <h5 class="sub-title">@image.ImageName</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <img src="@image.ImageLink" alt="@image.ImageName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center top-buffer">
                                <br />
                                @image.ImageDescription
                            </div>
                            @if (image.BulletPoints.Any())
                            {
                                <br />

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach (var item in image.BulletPoints)
                                        {
                                            <li><i class="lni-check-mark-circle"></i> @item</li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </section>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    private Project _project { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _project = await projectService.GetProjectAsync(Slug);

        if (_project == null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears both locally and on a published azure site.

[image: The error]

The site is deployed on azure for now. Mind you it is in Dutch.
The error appears when going to portfolio page, clicking on one of the three projects and then hard refreshing.
https://dogasolutions.azurewebsites.net/

EDIT: after fixing the references by adding a '/' (thanks to gsharp), the page seems to reload fine except for the blazor javascript file.

In the _host.cshtml inside the body tags:

```
<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
</app>

<script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: When refreshing, your app tries to access https://dogasolutions.azurewebsites.net/project/assets/js/slick.min.js but the file is located at https://dogasolutions.azurewebsites.net/assets/js/slick.min.js .. check where you reference your scripts... proably you sould reference it as "/assets/js/slick.min.js" and not as "assets/js/slick.min.js"

Comment: That is exactly what was happening! Thank you. However, the blazor javascript file won't work this way. The page does reload correctly, but the console still logs an error about blazor. (see my edit)

Comment: I think the blazor file is fine without "/" as it's added by the framework. can you give it a try?

Comment: Without the "/" it gives a 404 to the script as before. I thought it would be logical that it would work without it since it is so by default, but it does not apparently.

Comment: Where  do you have your "_framework/blazor.server.js" (host.cshtml, layout.cshtml, layout.razor,...)?  can you post the code? is dogasolution.azurewebsites.net the same site as https://dogasolutions.azurewebsites.net/portfolio ?

Comment: Ive edited the question. It is inside the _host.cshtml file inside the body tags. Portfolio is a page on the site. So yes it is the same site

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the culprit was. I used an online template to replace most of my `_Host.cshtml` file. By doing so I had overwritten the `base` tag in my `head` tag.

Simply adding the following code inside my `head` tag fixed the issue completely.

```
<base href="~/" />
```

Without this, blazor cannot correctly resolve the connection when going into detail pages (e.g. domain/page/{parameter})